# How to apply fomatter and template settings to multiple projects in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, settings, multi-project

I have various interrelated projects in my Eclipse Helios workspace.  Some projects use the Java standard coding style with no license header.  Some others use similar coding style with 3-space indentation with LGPL 2.1 license header.  Some others use tab indentation with Apache License 2 header.  They all do not store Eclipse project settings in their version control system, so they need to be configured once they are imported to the Eclipse workbench.

What I want to do is to apply the same formatter and template settings (+ some Java compiler settings?) to the modules that belong to the same project.  I tried to select them either using control + click or grouping them with a working set, but both didn't allow me to update any project-specific settings.

Ideally, it would be nice if I can map a working set with its project-specific settings (e.g. Apply this and this to all projects which belong to the working set 'X'), but I wouldn't even complain if I have to right-click on a working set every time I import a new project.

How can I do this?  Is there any plugin that does the job?  Is there any workaround for the limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No really good way to handle this beyond take one project and apply your settings and then copy the .settings/*jdt* file(s) to the projects you want it applied to.

Comment: sadly this is still true in 2021

Answer (score 1):

another idea is to export/import your preferences.
menu: file/export
open category "general"
choose entry "preferences"

same goes for the import.